# Generate partial XML string

Tags: java, xml

I want to create an XML string from a Document object with root tag unclosed. Is there any way to do so?

Please consider the following snippet

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
         DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

         // root element
         Element rootElement = doc.createElement("cars");
         Attr attrType = doc.createAttribute("type");
         attrType.setValue("formula one");
         rootElement.setAttributeNode(attrType);
         doc.appendChild(rootElement);


         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

         StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
         transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

This will output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><cars type="formula one"/>
```

But the result I needed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><cars type="formula one">
```

What changes I have to do to get this result?

Comment: Expected and output are same. Please edit the desired result

Comment: No, There is no closing tag in expected output, please check @F.K.M.N

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan This sounds like an XY problem, why do you want to create an invalid XML document/fragment?

Comment: It is not an invalid document - it is required to create an XMPP initial stream header where a close tag is sent only  after a complete chat session.@Progman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use XMLStreamWriter  as DocumentBuilderFactory closes the tags by default

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;



public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        try{


        }catch(Exception  e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```